# Ubuntu won't boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb

Just made my USB bootable via pendrivelinux but now when I reboot I can't choose the USB - my only options to show up are Windows 7 and Ubuntu from a previous wubi version I used (won't boot, btw)
What do I do?

Comment: What is your system make? Have you checked the BIOS to make sure the boot priority number 1 is set to USB?

Comment: that's my propblem now, i'm using a sony vaio which is supposed to acces BIOS via F2 but nothing happens when i reboot ..

Answer (score 0):

go to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD 
Read: "BIOS is not set to boot from CD or DVD drive"

Hope I could help you! :)

Comment: That's for booting from a CD or DVD, but Josef wants to boot from a USB drive, so he should select `Removable Devices` rather than `CD-ROM Drive` as in that article. Furthermore, when relying on external sources, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. So you may want to edit your post to expand it and account for the difference between booting to a USB flash drive and booting to an optical drive.